# Why am I getting different results between CMD and VBS?

Tags: cmd, vbscript, wmic

When I issue the following command in a CMD prompt, the correct value is returned for the AdapterRAM object:

```
WMIC Path Win32_VideoController Get AdapterRAM
```

The correct value of 8589934592 is returned. However when I utilize VBScript with the same query, an incorrect value is returned for the same AdapterRam object:

```
sPC = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & sPC & "\root\cimv2")
Set cSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select AdapterRAM From Win32_VideoController Where DeviceID='VideoController1'")
For Each oPC in cSettings
    GPURAMSize = oPC.AdapterRAM
    WScript.Echo GPURAMSize
Next
```

The incorrect value of -1048576 is returned for the same AdapterRAM object.

Am I missing something here? Why the difference in values returned between utilizing the same query from a CMD prompt versus a VBScript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It exceeds the value that fits into 32 bit. VBScript integers are signed. So 0 to 2gig. After 2 gig they count down to -1.

Comment: Your code also doesn't work so it returns nothing but errors.

Comment: replace `objWMIService` with `oWMISvc`, remove `Set` from `Set GPURAMSize = oPC.AdapterRAM`

Comment: Ok. So, once I've modified the code, I'm still getting that negative number. Is there no way around that?

Comment: In addition, when I'm querying the value for TotalPhysicalMemory from Win32_ComputerSystem, which is another digit larger than that of the AdapterRAM from Win32_VideoController, it doesn't change to a negative number...it displays properly.

Comment: For example, [wmic path win32_computersystem get totalphysicalmemory] returns [67897032704] and [wmic path win32_videocontroller get adapterram] returns [4293918720] and [1073741824]...one entry for each video adapter.

Comment: `uint32   AdapterRAM;` specifies that it returns a unsigned 32 bit integer. VBScript (and VBA) only support singed integers. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-videocontroller. While `uint64   TotalPhysicalMemory;` specifies a 64 bit unsigned integer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem.

Comment: Signed integers use two complements. So in 32 bit it counts up to ½ way and then counts down to -1. So up to 2 gig then down from 2 gig to -1 rather than 0 to 4 gig. In a CPU the transistors that do addition also can do subtraction by adding numbers using 2 complements This saves on transistor counts. Makes CPUs cheaper.

Comment: So, no way to get the actual number to display?

Comment: I don't have excessive memory. Does `GPURAMSize = CDbl(oPC.AdapterRAM)` help.

Comment: Sadly, no. Same issue with same negative number.

Comment: VBScript doesn't support uint32 and never will. See [this thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/5vjkof/comment/de2up0f/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) should help, explains a workaround that pulls the value back as text `GetObjectText_(0)`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I'm even able to use the resultant string with math and rounding. Thanx!

Comment: @user3208239 Excellent, post the solution as an answer, it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanx to all the help from everyone that has contributed comments, but most especially user 692942 for providing the link that helped me solve the problem. Here's what I came up with...

```
strComputer = "."
Dim VideoController, PosValueBegin, PosValueEnd, Length, StringToFind
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set cSetting = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select Name, Manufacturer, Model, SystemSKUNumber, TotalPhysicalMemory From Win32_ComputerSystem")
mathConversion = 1024 * 1024 * 1024
Set cSetting = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select DeviceID, Caption, AdapterRAM From Win32_VideoController Where DeviceID='VideoController1'")
For Each objComputer in cSetting
    GPUID = objComputer.Caption
Next
For Each objComputer in cSetting
    StringToFind = "AdapterRAM = "
    VideoController = objComputer.GetObjectText_(0)
    PosValueBegin = InStr(VideoController, StringToFind) + Len(StringToFind)
    PosValueEnd = InStr(PosValueBegin, VideoController, ";")
    Length = PosValueEnd - PosValueBegin
    ActualNumber = Mid(VideoController, PosValueBegin, Length)
    GPURAMSize = RoundUp(ActualNumber / mathConversion)
Next
wScript.Echo "GPU:  " & GPUID & " (" & GPURAMSize & "GB)"
wScript.Quit
```

Comment: You have a typo on line 18 : You should wtite `GPURAMSize = Round(ActualNumber / mathConversion)` instead of `GPURAMSize = RoundUp(ActualNumber / mathConversion)`